# Encountering file not found error in production

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I hosted my django project on vercel, every static file is working correctly.
django views.py function

```
def view_pdf(request):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media', 'Shashank_Joshi_resume.pdf')
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), content_type='application/pdf')  instead of mimetype
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="Shashank_Joshi_resume.pdf"'  
        return response
```

html template

```
<div class="resume">
              <input type="button" value="Resume" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.open('view_pdf')">
            </div>
```

error im getting
FileNotFoundError at /view_pdf
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/task/static/media/Shashank_Joshi_resume.pdf'

But i have button in my html template by which a pdf file is shown when i click that its showing file not found error on vercel but when i run it locally its working totally fine. The github repo is also upto date.

Comment: Its a debugging issue. Did you run collectstatic? Also maybe ssh to see if the files exists where it suppose to?

Answer (score -1):

Did you set MEDIA_ROOT in your settings.py? check it 
As ruddra said, run your collectstatic 
At the end you can debug your code, like print your file_path 
I hope this helps